# create or replace view

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Hello I am having trouble with create of replace view in SQL.
What I am trying to do is create or replace a view that shows the top 5 selling products of the week and invoices older than 5 days without a shipping ID. this is what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW helper.manager_view AS 
SELECT Inv_Num, Line_Num, P_Code
FROM helper.LINE
WHERE 
UNION 
SELECT 
Inv_DATE AS ENTRY_DATE,  
FROM helper.INVOICE 
WHERE Inv_Date >
ORDER BY Inv_Date
```

Comment: What database are we talking about?  What errors or other output do you get when you run the above?

Comment: oracle sql developer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your databases supports `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` (not all do), you have several problems, noted below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW helper.manager_view AS 
    SELECT Inv_Num, Line_Num, P_Code
    FROM helper.LINE
    WHERE 
----------^ Uh, what goes here?
    UNION 
    SELECT Inv_DATE AS ENTRY_DATE,  
-----------^ Same number and types of arguments as in the first `SELECT`
    FROM helper.INVOICE 
    WHERE Inv_Date >
---------------------^ Uh, what goes here?
    ORDER BY Inv_Date
-------------^ There is no `Inv_Date` in the first `SELECT`
```

Comment: this is for sql developer. ok look like I am way off. in reference to your comments i do not know what goes there and i am not 100% sure if it is needed

Comment: @hamburgerhelper . . . Perhaps you should ask *another* question with sample data and desired results, asking what the correct query is.  Don't modify this question -- you will invalidate this answer and that is impolite.